# Навигация по экранам

Tags: javascript

Приветствую.
Делаю навигацию на лендинге по секциям.
Проблема, такая ошибка:

> Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

на строке:

```
var reqSectionPos = reqSection.offset().top;
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.link').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    showSection($(this).attr('href'), true);
  });

  showSection(window.location.hash, false);
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  checkSection();
});

function showSection(section, isAnimate) {
  var direction = section.replace(/#/, '');
  var reqSection = $('.section').filter('[data-section="' + direction + '"]');
  var reqSectionPos = reqSection.offset().top;

  if (isAnimate) {
    $('body, html').animate({
      scrollTop: reqSectionPos
    }, 600);
  } else {
    $('body, html').scrollTop(reqSectionPos);
  }
}

function checkSection() {
  $('.section').each(function() {
    var
      $this = $(this),
      topEdge = $this.offset().top,
      bottomEdge = topEdge + $this.height(),
      wScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (topEdge < wScroll && bottomEdge > wScroll) {
      var
        currentId = $this.data('section');
      reqLink = $('.link').filter('[href="#' + currentId + '"]');

      reqLink.closest('item').addClass('active')
        .siblings().removeClass('active');

      window.location.hash = currentId;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.section {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
}
.item .active {
  border: 3px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item"><a class="link" href="#">one</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item"><a class="link" href="#">two</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item"><a class="link" href="#">three</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="wrapper" style="height: 100%;">
  <div data-section="one" class="section" style=" background: #000;">title1</div>
  <div data-section="two" class="section" style="background: #434;">title2</div>
  <div data-section="three" class="section" style="background: #919;">title3</div>
</div>
```

[Код в песочнице](https://jsfiddle.net/gubmLc5o/1/)

Comment: **весь** необходимый код должен быть непосредственно в вопросе. Ссылка может служить дополнением

Comment: а какой результат вы ожидали меняя в строке `"#"` знак `#` на ''?

Comment: удалить решетку из href

Comment: но в примере, все href - это "#" и удалив решетку, получите всегда пустую строку

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае идет попытка определить секцию, к которой надо перейти, получается урл.

Но в разметке у всех ссылок стоит `href="#"`

Поэтому селектор ниже

```
$('.section').filter('[data-section="' + direction + '"]')
```

не находит ни одного элемента удовлетворяющего условию, так как `direction` для всех ссылок - пустая строка.

Нужно указать каждой ссылке соответствующую секцию.

А так же добавить проверку, на случай того, что hash не указан.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.link').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    showSection($(this).attr('href'), true);
  });

  showSection(window.location.hash, false);
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  checkSection();
});

function showSection(section, isAnimate) {
  var direction = section.replace(/#/, '')||'one';
  var reqSection = $('.section').filter('[data-section="' + direction + '"]');
  var reqSectionPos = reqSection.offset().top;

  if (isAnimate) {
    $('body, html').animate({
      scrollTop: reqSectionPos
    }, 600);
  } else {
    $('body, html').scrollTop(reqSectionPos);
  }
}

function checkSection() {
  $('.section').each(function() {
    var
      $this = $(this),
      topEdge = $this.offset().top,
      bottomEdge = topEdge + $this.height(),
      wScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (topEdge < wScroll && bottomEdge > wScroll) {
      var
        currentId = $this.data('section');
      reqLink = $('.link').filter('[href="#' + currentId + '"]');

      reqLink.closest('item').addClass('active')
        .siblings().removeClass('active');

      window.location.hash = currentId;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.section {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
}
.item .active {
  border: 3px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item"><a class="link" href="#one">one</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item"><a class="link" href="#two">two</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item"><a class="link" href="#three">three</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="wrapper" style="height: 100%;">
  <div data-section="one" class="section" style=" background: #000;">title1</div>
  <div data-section="two" class="section" style="background: #434;">title2</div>
  <div data-section="three" class="section" style="background: #919;">title3</div>
</div>
```